# Cannot install gotk3, getting GdkMonitor error

Tags: go, gtk3

I tried to use gotk3 for creating desktop application. I follow the instruction in gotk3 [wiki](https://github.com/gotk3/gotk3/wiki) and this [installing-on-linux wiki](https://github.com/gotk3/gotk3/wiki/Installing-on-Linux) to install it. But then I get this error while executing `go get -v`:

```
gcc errors for preamble:
In file included from ../../gotk3/gotk3/gdk/gdk_since_3_22.go:23:0:
./gdk_since_3_22.go.h:22:8: error: unknown type name 'GdkMonitor'
 static GdkMonitor *
        ^
```

I've tried to delete the gotk3 directory, and then trying to `go get -v` again, but still, it didn't work.

I also checked the GTK version that installed in my Ubuntu 16.04 using `apt-cache policy libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 | grep Installed`. And it shows this:

```
  Installed: 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2
  Installed: 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3
```

What did I do wrong? Thanks

Comment: Have you install the *dev* packages as indicated on the wiki you specified above?

Comment: Yeah, I did. I've run `sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev libcairo2-dev libglib2.0-dev` as it written in the wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GdkMonitor was introduced in GTK+ 3.22. Your version is 3.18.

`go get -tags gtk_3_18 github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gtk` at the very beginning of building ([see here NOTE section](https://github.com/gotk3/gotk3/wiki)) should fix things